# htaccess url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

Is there an easy way to 301 redirect

http://www.site-name.com/yellow-cars

to

http://www.site-name.com/shop/catalog/all/Yellow_Cars

I'm not sure if the last segment in the URL can be created in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like:

```
RewriteMap capitalize int:toupper
RewriteRule /(\w)(\w+)-(\w)(\w+) /shop/catalog/all/${capitalize:$1}$2_${capitalize:$3}$4 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap):

## `dehyphen.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
  print '_'.join(s.capitalize() for s in line.split('-'))
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

## httpd conf:

```
RewriteMap dehyphen prg:dehyphen.py
RewriteRule /(.+) /shop/catalog/all/${dehyphen:$1} [L]
```

Make sure that dehyphen.py is made executable.